# How to show push notification in the app just like instagram show in notification activity

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am developing an android app that receives push notification from Firebase console, but my problem is how to show this notifications in the application just like Instagram and Facebook both shows notification in the app.[image: happen app notification page]

I want to show just like happen app show notification in the app.

Comment: What you want to do? Something like the 'people who liked your pics' tab in instagram?

Comment: yeah, exactly is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your comment you don't want something related to push, you need an user story.

Since i don't program JAVA i can't help you with the programming part and codes, but i can help on the logic and the rest you can figure out. And since i don't know the segment of your app i'll do everything thinking on Instagram.

**THE 'PEOPLE WHO LIKED/FOLLOWED YOU' PART:**

You'll need an UserStories node where you'll save an userID node and, inside that node, you'll push data of the person who liked/followed your picture.

Lets imagine i'm a user, my name is `Gabriel` and my id is `1234`, le'ts say i also have a picture whose link is `https://firebasestorage.etc`. If i like your post you save something like this on Firebase

```
DataBase
|_ UserStories
   |_ YourUserID
      |_ -TheKeyFirebasePushMethodGenerated
        |_ name: "Gabriel"
        |_ id: 1234
        |_ pic: "https://firebasestorage.etc"
```

So everytime you enter your `people who liked` page you'll get your recent user stories under your id, iterate through it and build your page. You can get like only the last 30, or suit yourself with the number you like, or a infinite scroll.

**THE PUSH NOTIFICATION**

You can do a push with number of people who liked your post, if you have something in your back-end with an observable/watcher who keeps an eye in every `UserStories` with `once child_added` method, you can use it to get the user key, the number of times it was fired and send a push to that user incrementing every time someone likes and, when the user opens the app/click the push, you set that number to 0.

And you can do better, take all `child_added` and the last one you'll use as the push icon and title.

**TOO MANY STORIES**

You can also use this idea of `child_added` to keep your database clean, ok i know the user story is like a log and it's good to have all entries, but you can make something like `if it has more than 1000 entries, delete the first entry`.

So i don't know if this can give you ideas to solve your problem, other user commentaries based on what i said are also a good ideia, but i hope this helps.

Comment: thnks bro its very helpful, i have another question is that when we want to sent all users of app then how ? for example let an university app and teacher want to send message to all student about schedule of exam that can be show in app as.

Comment: For this to work, in a university app example, you'll need a `class` node on firebase, inside you'll order by hatever is better to you, a teacher's id, a class name, a semester and inside every class you can have a list of students with their id. So when you need to send a push, go to a especific class, iterate through it, get the user token and send push. It's basically it, the class node will work like a friends list of facebook, for example.

Comment: Remember to always update the token of the user saved on firebase and add rules like: `if user logout, remove the tokens, if it logs in another device, register 2 tokens`. And always have and option of disable push, not everyone likes pushs and excessive pushs can be the end of and app. But this is just my opinion. Anything you need just ask :D

Answer (score 0):

When using FCM, notifications will never show "in the application". They only show when the app is in the background. Instagram and Facebook are able to do this because they probably don't use FCM.

Comment: Then how can i do that ?